# Type object error while trying to inherit a form.Models base class with UserCreationForm base class

Tags: python, django, forms, inheritance

(This write-up had alot of typographical errors earlier, was typing fast and frankly I was tired, so I didn't really take note)

I was trying to inherit a form class object which uses forms.ModelForm into a different form class object which inherits from UserCreationForm. I understand that when form models are being inherited, only one Meta supersedes. However, I still gave it a shot as that's the only way to achieve the business logic I am trying to arrive at.

The codes below, pls kindly look through and suggest a work around:

```
class AddressMixin(forms.ModelForm):
    class Meta:
        model = Subscriber
        fields = ['address_one', 'address_two', 'city', 'province']
        widgets = {
            'address_one':forms.TextInput(attrs={'class':'form-control'}),
            'address_two':forms.TextInput(attrs={'class':'form-control'}),
            'city': forms.TextInput(attrs={'class':'form-control'}),
            'province': forms.TextInput(attrs={'class':'form-control'}),
    }

class SubscriberForm(AddressMixin,UserCreationForm):
    first_name = forms.CharField(required=True, widget=forms.TextInput(attrs={'class':'form-control'}))
    last_name = forms.CharField(required=True, widget=forms.TextInput(attrs={'class':'form-control'}))
    email = forms.EmailField(required=True, widget=forms.TextInput(attrs={'class':'form-control'}))
    username = forms.CharField(widget=forms.TextInput(attrs={'class':'form-control'}))
    password1 = forms.CharField(widget=forms.TextInput(attrs={'class':'form-control', 'type':'password'}))
    password2 = forms.CharField(widget=forms.TextInput(attrs={'class':'form-control', 'type':'password'}))
```

Here's the error I am getting,

```
AttributeError at /subscribe/signup/
type object 'Subscriber' has no attribute 'USERNAME_FIELD'
```

Again, I understand the error is referring to the subscriber model not having username as an attribute, because the AddressMixin Meta supersedes. However the AddressMixin model contains some business logic methods that needs to be submitted during registration, hence, it needs to pass through the same form.

Any advice will help, while I keep trying to figure it out.

P.S here's the full traceback to the Error...

```
Traceback:

File "/home/ibrokola/Desktop/PersonalProjects/toLaunch/SaaS/CRM/crm/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/core/handlers/exception.py" in inner
```

41.             response = get_response(request)

```
File "/home/ibrokola/Desktop/PersonalProjects/toLaunch/SaaS/CRM/crm/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/core/handlers/base.py" in _get_response
```

187.                 response = self.process_exception_by_middleware(e, request)

```
File "/home/ibrokola/Desktop/PersonalProjects/toLaunch/SaaS/CRM/crm/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/core/handlers/base.py" in _get_response
```

185.                 response = wrapped_callback(request, *callback_args, **callback_kwargs)

```
File "/home/ibrokola/Desktop/PersonalProjects/toLaunch/SaaS/CRM/src/subscribers/views.py" in subscriber_new
```

81.     else: form = SubscriberForm()

```
File "/home/ibrokola/Desktop/PersonalProjects/toLaunch/SaaS/CRM/crm/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/contrib/auth/forms.py" in __init__
```

94.         if self._meta.model.USERNAME_FIELD in self.fields:

```
Exception Type: AttributeError at /subscribe/signup/
Exception Value: type object 'Subscriber' has no attribute 'USERNAME_FIELD'
```

Comment: Please show full traceback and `UserCreationForm` definition.

Comment: UserCreationForm was imported from django.contrib.auth.forms, will add full traceback as edit to the or question...